# ORA-01843: not a valid month when insert a date in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, insert

I'm trying to insert a row in oracle database and when i try with the date i have the errore in title.
My date is `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` (example `25/01/2013 12:07:19`)

edit for better explain:
i have an android application and want to insert a row in oracle database by php.
in Php i have:

```
$sqlString = sprintf("INSERT INTO GUASTI (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) 
                      VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
                      ,'guasto','tipo','data', 'localita', 'indirizzo_id', 'utente_id',
                       $array['guasto'], $array['tipo'], $array['data'], $array['localita'], $idUtenti, $idIndirizzo);
```

where `$array['data']` is `25/01/2013 12:07:19`

p.s. i know that there are security problems there but it is not a problem for now.

Comment: And what is the code you are using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MM` is for month. Use `MI` for minutes.

You have

```
HH:MM:SS
```

every time where the minutes are greater than 12 will trigger the error as you are telling Oracle to interpret them as months.

You are also using HH without am/pm (in your example you just used `12`). If you are using a 24 format use `HH24`

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS
```

or if you want the 12-hour format

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SSAM
```

and then

```
02/01/2013 07:42:00am
```

**Edit**

You are inserting the date with the default format which is MM/DD/YYYY (american standard): 25 is not a valid month. You can use the `TO_DATE` function

```
'TO_DATE(' . $array['data'] . ', DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS)'
```

Comment: nono i wrong to write.. i means minutes there so it is HH:MI:SS (it was only an example for my formatting) didn't remember the tag for minutes :)

Comment: @Atomico, then update your question with a valid example that generates the error.

Comment: ahh ty Sonal answer too but i didn't understand the answer so i give you the correct answer because you follow me with edit :) ty

Comment: ehm i think it worked but when i go on the database i see that my date is recorded as 01/03/2013 (not time and it convert at MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: @Atomico how did you 'go' to the database? Which is the type of the column? You can specify the format in the `SELECT` clause (`select to_char(data, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`)

Comment: by apex .. well it show only the date but if i write select to_char(data, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') it show the full data.. so it is only a visual thing. can i put something in my oracle database to set the default data show at DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS?

Answer (score 4):

Use TO_DATE('20/08/2012 09:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') while inserting date for more details see link [Oracle Error](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01843.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just for more info:

The following pattern letters are defined (all other characters from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are reserved):

Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples

```
G   Era designator  Text    AD
y   Year    Year    1996; 96
Y   Week year   Year    2009; 09
M   Month in year (context sensitive)   Month   July; Jul; 07
L   Month in year (standalone form) Month   July; Jul; 07
w   Week in year    Number  27
W   Week in month   Number  2
D   Day in year Number  189
d   Day in month    Number  10
F   Day of week in month    Number  2
E   Day name in week    Text    Tuesday; Tue
u   Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)    Number  1
a   Am/pm marker    Text    PM
H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
k   Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12
m   Minute in hour  Number  30
s   Second in minute    Number  55
S   Millisecond Number  978
z   Time zone   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z   Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
X   Time zone   ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00
```